# Android UI update notification

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I am having 3 Edittexts and 3 spinner in my view, Whenever there is change in any edittext text value or change in any spinner selection I have to make service cal , How do I get notify like there is change in edittext or spinner selection?

Comment: Check the documentation for EditText and Spinner to see if there isn't possibly an event listener you can attach to. Spoiler-alert: There is. Read the documentation first.

Comment: @323go you beat me to it. If there was an award for least research made before posting to SO, this question should be nominated. Also, the question title is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add listeners to the EditTexts and Spinners.

For the EditTexts try this:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

And for the Spinners try this:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the api documentation? All android views have pretty clear listener apis. EditText / TextView is no exception: [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Spinners have: [setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: This really ought to be a comment, and the question should be voted too broad.

Comment: Why should this be a comment? It answers the question and has references to the two apis needed. Essentially it's the same as the other answer that was given later, and accepted. Yes, the question could have been voted for closing, but too broad? Rather too little effort..